# How to post a request and download file to disk with angular?

Tags: angularjs

In angular, I want to download a text file containing a csv of userdata. Usually I have a form with a post action, but I want the user to stay on the same page, but return the csv data without any page referesh. The following is my post command:

```
$http({
    url: "api/getUserData",
        method: "POST",
        data:{user_id:app.user_id}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // data gets returned here
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
});
```

My problem is, the "data" that comes back from the post is a csv file. how can I get the data to actually "download" to the user's computer instead of living in the javascript? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36140420/6094740)  is the link to solution. It uses HTML5 FileSaver API to save the file as BLOB

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

1. Create temporary anchor ,
2. encode, your data & name your file using download attribute,
3. and then, fire a click event on it.
4. finally, remove the inserted element .

   ```
   $http({
       url: "api/getUserData",
       method: "POST",
       data:{user_id:app.user_id}
   }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      // data gets returned here
      var anchor = angular.element('<a/>'); 

      angular.element(document.body).append(anchor); // Attach to document

      anchor.attr({
          href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(data),
          target: '_blank',
          download: 'myFileName.csv'
      })[0].click(); // fire a click event.

      anchor.remove(); // Clean it now ...

   }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       $scope.status = status;
   });
   ```